# SQL last month date of given date

Tags: sql, join

i am using sql 
How to get the last day of the month for a given date

01/03/2014 should return 01/31/2014
 I only need the date part.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For SQL-SERVER, try this:

```
SELECT convert(varchar,(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,'01/03/2014 ')+1,0))),101)
```